# Which Marvel Superhero does this logo belong to?

Tags: marvel, object-identification

A colleague has an accessory with a collection of Marvel Character logos and we haven't been able to identify one, with Google not yielding anything helpful, It has a Hydra and an Avengers logo so maybe it's not a hero, but a group it represents. It also has a Loki helmet so villains are also a possibility.

This also isn't like official merch so it might be an unofficial logo.

Please see image below. The unknown one is circled in red.

[image: Marvel logos]

Comment: The logo labelled falcon is actually shield, oops.

Comment: It looks a bit like Ultimate Hawkeye's target logo. https://imgur.com/gallery/ndfjKMR

Comment: The closest I can find is probably Deathlok (see [this cover](https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/marveldatabase/images/b/b2/Deathlok_Vol_5_3.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20141215000205)) but it's not an exact match.

Comment: This [AliExpress listing](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32893491164.html) attributes the symbol to MCU Hawkeye. Still looking for something more official, but perhaps this isn't an official symbol at all.

Comment: This [Etsy listing](https://www.etsy.com/uk/listing/1303444041/hero-keyring-hawkeye-ironman-charms-clip?click_key=d2e36b98aa0aee3a7713379cc95024ae3994ec5c%3A1303444041&click_sum=5ea4d986&ref=related-3) features the same keyring, also attributed to Hawkeye.

Comment: I think LogicDictates' links confirm that is just a cheaply made Hawkeye logo.

Comment: It's the Deadpool one that seems out of place to me, being the only character/organization so far not represented in the MCU.  Maybe this is inspired more by the comics, but then we're using an MCU-only logo for Hawkeye, so I don't know...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman The circled A is also a trademark of the MCU's Avengers. As far as I can tell, they never circled the A before (although I will have to admit the Internet is so riddled with MCU Avengers logo that I'm having a hard time finding anything else).

Comment: @Clockwork - That would make a pretty interesting question. The A with the arrow certainly pre-dates the film (this comic book one is from 2009, for example - https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gJHg.png)

Comment: @Valorum To be fair, I hesitated to ask about the evolution of Avengers' logo throughout the age when I felt like I kept falling into the movie logos, but thought otherwise when I figured there might actually be nothing but just the stylised word "Avengers". I guess I'm just going to sleep on it and see if I change my mind again (or if someone else jumped on the idea when I wake up).

Comment: @Clockwork The other possibility is that isn't actually Deadpool but Spider-Man - they have similar masks, though I'd expect a Spider-Man keyring to use the spider symbol on his chest, but who knows?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your charm bracelet is a fairly poor quality knock-off (presumably from Etsy or similar) of this [Marvel-licenced charm bracelet by Athena](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Avengers-Logo-Charm-Bracelet-Movie-Series-Jewelry-Multi-Charms-Wristlet-Superheroes-Brand-Marvel-Movie-Collection/210293831).

I found this keychain with a similar logo in higher quality. The mark on the rear identifies it as "**Hawkeye**".

[image]

Comment: Pretty definitive, thank you!

Comment: @LiefdeWen - The hardest thing was to find a licensed thing with this logo. It's a pretty rare one

Comment: not enough love for hawkeye :(

Comment: Google Images turns up [very different logos for Hawkeye](https://www.google.com/search?q=hawkeye+logo+marvel&tbm=isch)

Comment: @Henry - Yes, this is definitely a rare one

Comment: @bracco23 [You know... I'm not so sure I wanna be part of a team I have to rescue every week...](https://youtu.be/kL3kV2s5kfk?t=138)