# What is the evolution of the Avengers' logo and title throughout the years?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, comics, avengers

When I looked at [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/275764/which-marvel-superhero-does-this-logo-belong-to) which was asked recently about identifying a Marvel superhero's logo, the first thing that I noticed was the fact the A logo was circled, which I suddenly felt was specific to the Marvel Cinematic Universe.

Out of curiosity, I tried checking if the Avengers had a logo of any kind before that, or if all they had was a stylised "Avengers" on the comics cover.

To my disappointment, my searches so far have been moot, because I keep finding images of the Marvel Cinematic Universe's movies title. The only thing I was able to find was that the original "Avengers" stylised title was created by the designer Gasper Saladino in 1972:

[image: An Avengers title in black and white, similar to how it was originally drawn by the aforementioned designer]

Has the Avengers' title and logo changed throughout the years?

Comment: Are you only interested in answers from the comics?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage I'm interested in all the logos, including the MCU. What I don't want though is an answer that only focus on the MCU.

Comment: I've added tags for *both* to hopefully make that clearer. I suspect you'll either get two separate answers, or 'lopsided' answers but your question probably isn't too broad to stay as it is.

Comment: This might be quite a large answer. Just in the MCU they've had at least seven or eight versions of the logo, not to mention the fifty years they've been around in the comics

Comment: For the title from the comics, at least, it's quite easy to go through the covers at https://www.coverbrowser.com/covers/avengers and see how it's changed (it appears the one posted in the question is the third variant).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are all the *Avengers* logos I could find.

**1963-1972**

[image]

**1969** (Issues #62-#29)

[image]

**1972-1982**

Here we see the arrow in the A for the first time as well as the typical font we are used to seeing today.

[image]

**1982-1983**

[image]

**1983-1984**

[image]

**1984-1985**

[image]

**1985-1989**

[image]

**1989-1994**

[image]

**1994 (Issue #380)**

[image]

**1994-1995**

[image]

**1995-1996**

[image]

**1996-1997**

[image]

**1998-2004**

[image]

**2004**

[image]

**2010-2013**

[image]

**The Avengers (2012)**

[image]

**2013-2013**

[image]

**2015**

[image]

**Avengers: Age of Ultron (2015)**

[image]

**2017-2018**

[image]

**2018**

[image]

**2018-Present**

[image]

**Avengers: Infinity War (2018)**

[image]

**Avengers: Endgame (2019)**

[image]

**Avengers: Kang Dynasty**

[image]

This information is based on this [article](https://logos.fandom.com/wiki/The_Avengers_(comic_book)). Please feel free to add or edit if you find anything else.

Comment: Impressive, it's changed more than I thought it would (although that was to be expected).

Comment: https://cdn.marvel.com/u/prod/marvel/i/mg/8/f0/5bff092a216f0/clean.jpg looks unique as well.

Comment: Yeah it looks like the west coast avengers have a whole different list of logos